# Multiple comparatives of different types: how to choose?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, adjectives, comparatives

I have an eight-month-old daughter. Her experiments in mobility led me to contemplate phrases like

> the dirtier and messier, the better.

What happens if one (but not both) of the adjectives before the comma is replaced with a word that forms a comparative with "more" rather than the suffix *-er*? For example, replace "messy" with "dangerous." Neither of the following sound quite satisfactory to my ear:

> the dirtier and more dangerous, the better
>   the more dirty and dangerous, the better

Is one of these actually correct? Is there some other solution that isn't coming to mind?

Comment: I dunno, but I do love this grammatical construction. When I first read about it I was astonished that English actually has *custom grammar* for expressing strong statistical correlation—and that I had never realized this before. Trivia: the *the* in this construction is actually [etymologically unrelated to](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/the) the article *the*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of the two alternatives, the first is correct:

> The dirtier and more dangerous, the better.

The phrase 'more dirty' is simply incorrect.

Change 'dirty' into 'beguiling', and then you can write:

> The more beguiling and dangerous, the better.

Comment: What an odd substitution.  Why that particular word?

Comment: @Kevin: the 37th neutrino whistling past a neuron at the moment triggered a random association at the instant I was typing.  It was a quasi-random choice.  Also, dirt and mess are attractive to 8 month old babies, and hence beguiling to them.

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe find a more pliable ('pliabler!) word than 'dangerous':

"The dirtier and (the) riskier, the better."